# Auto-Lock Lubuntu in 10 minutes

Tags: lubuntu

I wish to auto lock the desktop after 10 minutes and have a password protected login screen open up.
Power Manager has a light-lock feature but it locks after screensaver and there is no screensaver preference in Lubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This is for Lubuntu 18.04.  I have not tried it on the lxqt desktop.

1) Disable light-locker

```
sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/light-locker.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/light-locker.desktop.bak
```

2) Install xscreensaver

```
sudo apt install xscreensaver
```

3) Configure

- Set options in xscreensaver-demo
- set xscreensaver to autostart options with -nosplash option
- In Power Manager/Display set toggle to OFF

Comment: Thank you so much. I read good things about iLock and  xautolock but that requires some scripting. Next time I will use the full Ubuntu district.